# filter data from dropdown and show related data in another component angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a header component and it has a dropdown that shows the company and there is another component it's showing all branch data. I want to show data only when I select a company from the header component. I can only able to filter data with a dropdown when it's in the same component.
below code is working in the branch component.

**Header component.ts**

```
companyData: [] = [];
companyId;

getCompany() {
    this.companyService.getCompanies().subscribe(x => {
      Object.assign(this.companyData, x);
    });
  }

  changeCompany(companyId) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
    console.log(companyId);
  }
```

**header.html**

```
    <li class="navbar-form">
      <div class="from-group">
        <select class="dropdown-item" (change)="changeCompany($event.target.value)">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Company</option>
          <option *ngFor="let comp of companyData" [value]="comp.Id">
            {{comp.Name}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>

    </li>
```

**branch component.ts**

```
  getBranches(companyId) {
    this.branchService.getBranches().subscribe(b => {
      Object.assign(this.branchData, b);

      this.branchData = this.branchData.filter(b => b.CompanyId == companyId);
    });
  }

  selectedCompany(company) {
    this.companyId = company;
    this.getBranches(company);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read more about sharing data between components: https://angular.io/guide/inputs-outputs

First, you should pass the **companyId** to **branch.component.ts**, eg:

```
<branch [companyId]="companyId"></branch>
```

Then, you should trigger **getBrunches()** when angular detects changes in the Input **companyId**.

**brunch.component.ts** should be look like:

```
export class BrunchComponent implements OnChanges{
@Input() companyId: any;

constructor(){
// some logic
}

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges){
 if('companyId' in changes){
   this.getBranches(this.companyId);
 }

 getBranches(companyId) {
    this.branchService.getBranches().subscribe(b => {
      Object.assign(this.branchData, b);

      this.branchData = this.branchData.filter(b => b.CompanyId == companyId);
    });
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your support. I'm not calling branch component it's going through a link